# mysql query error on my live server which I don't get on my test version of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Error

> Could not successfully run query (SELECT * FROM prior_approval WHERE id = \'187\') from DB: 
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'187\'' at line 2

PHP code:

```
$sql9 = "UPDATE prior_approval SET approved = 1, rejected = 0 WHERE id= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($app_id) . "'";
$result9 = mysql_query($sql9) or die(mysql_error());
```

The test  MySQL version is 5.6 and the live version is 5.1. An error message on the ISP's control panel says that the mysql version should be updated.

I have used mysqli as well but that failed so I reverted to mysql

using mysqli code:

```
$app_id = $_SESSION['app_id'];
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost',$username,$password,$database);
$sql9 = "UPDATE prior_approval SET approved = 1, rejected = 0 WHERE id= (?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql9);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$app_id);
$result9 = $stmt->execute();
```

Resulting error:

> Could not successfully run query (SELECT * FROM prior_approval WHERE id = \'187\') from DB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'187\'' at line 2

New error including vardump:

```
string(7) "\'187\'" 
Could not successfully run query (SELECT * FROM prior_approval WHERE id = \'187\') from DB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'187\'' at line 2
```

Table create:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prior_approval` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `approv_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dist_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dealer_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reporter` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `report_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_kind` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attach` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reply` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_oil` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nature_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `causal_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_descr` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `op_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_no_1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vin_1` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_date_1` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `km_reading_1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `repair_date_1` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `repl_no_1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `complaint_nature` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_repair` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `corr_action` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `act_result` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recommend` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `compl_period` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `compl_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `compl_freq` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `while_stopped` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `during_braking` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `during_acc_coast` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `during_forward_rev` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `during_turn` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `turn_speed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `during_rough` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rough_gear` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `during_decl_incr` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `during_any_speed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `during_decel_coast` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_brake` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_ac` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_defog` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_steer` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_wwash` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_starter` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_clutch` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_radio` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `using_other` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_idle` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_hot` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_start` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_cold` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_warm_up` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vary_car_speed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vary_engine_speed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vary_load` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vary_trunk_load` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `how_always` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `how_after` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `after_speed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attach1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attach2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attach3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `rejected` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rejected_reason` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=186 ;
```

Comment: Using prepared statements and query parameters may make the problem moot in this case.  (With the added bonus of being more of a defense against SQL injection.)  Dynamically building SQL queries from user input can often make it difficult to control the syntax, since the input could be *anything*.

Comment: You really should be moving to `mysqli` at the very least or PDO if you can. `mysql_query` has been removed from PHP 7 so this is dead code in the latest version. Are you sure that's the query you're running? It looks like it's been double escaped. This doesn't happen if you use prepared statements and placeholder values correctly, and that's not hard to get right.

Comment: Actually, as I said I already had prepared statements and mysqli, with the same result

Comment: also the input is taken from a record selected from a list so it is guaranteed to be ok. The error line says that the value is '\'187\'', the actual id is the integer 187.

Comment: Show the code with the mysqli statements and the error you get from that.

Comment: I have showed the mysqli code and resulting error above now

Comment: Why are you surrounding the id placeholder with parentheses? Show us how `$app_id` is set.

Comment: You're showing the wrong query. Your query is an `UPDATE` query, but your error is on a `SELECT` query.

Comment: I took out the parentheses. The result was the same error. I have shown abover   $app_id is taken from a session variable which is set in a calling module as:   $_SESSION['app_id']             = $_POST['app_id'];

Comment: Also the fact is that the error I get is SELECT although the query is UPDATE

Comment: Are you running a SELECT query anywhere else?

Comment: nowhere else in that module

Comment: Is there a SELECT inherent in an UPDATE?

Comment: and a `var_dump($app_id)` prior yields? And a `show create table prior_approval` shows? And your php/mysql character set is? The last is a fishing expedition but hey, brings up the topic.

Comment: There is no inherent `SELECT` in an `UPDATE`. Good eye @aynber - so where is this mysterious `SELECT` query?

Comment: @Drew I have put in the var_dump and the create table as requested, thanks. How do I check the php/mysql character set?

Comment: ok, you have a string, not an int. So that solves it right? @JayBlanchard you guys are the ones that can solve this. I am a poser. This question is over in my mind. It is a string. And we don't even know where in the code his error msg comes from (not that update stmt).

Comment: @Drew the error is on a `SELECT` query, not the `UPDATE` query as is shown in this question.

Comment: right. I just did an edit to my comment. this question is done.

Comment: @Geoff until you find the code where the `SELECT` statement is being performed we cannot solve this.

Comment: And even when you find that spot, you already know the problem. Thx to `var_dump` . Sometimes modify your code to do open for append msg statements out to a txt file. When it crashes, look at the file. Simple debug 101 here.

Comment: Thanks @Drew Jay and Aynber you all contributed to finding what the problem was. I will add how I converted the string to an integer to the code above

Comment: Just do a self-answer and accept it. As an answer. Don't put solutions in a question block. Otherwise you just confuse people. This question has been confusing enough :p

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the $app_id string to integer like this:

```
//$app_id = $_SESSION['app_id'];
$remove[] = "'";
$remove[] = "\\";
$app_id  = (int)str_replace($remove,"", $_SESSION['app_id']);
```

The later version of MySQL seems to convert automatically.